# Asp.net enableViewStateMac=true not hashing

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I've got an ASP.net web forms application.  I'm trying to work through some security issues with it.  Previously the developers before me had disabled MAC on the viewstate.  I'm trying to reenable it.

The problem I'm having is that I have pages `enableViewState="true"`, `enableViewStateMac="true"` and also a `machineKey` entry
in my web.config to do this globally, but the security tools I'm using are still reporting an unhashed viewstate.  I've searched the entire solution for any references to `EnableViewStateMac` in case there were page level directives turning it off and I'm not coming up with any.

So my question is this, what other ways/reasons would the application level directive not work?

Comment: What security tools are you using, and can you include an example of the unhashed viewstate?

Comment: I was using HP WebInspect, but am now also using Watcher, the Fiddler addon.  Both are throwing alerts for the vulnerability of an unhashed viewstate.  To validate that it isn't a false positive I created a default solution and ran it against that with the setting enabled and it didn't throw the alert, so unfortunately there is something within my application that is stopping it from working.  I'm just not sure what could do that.